# warn ./.cache/root.js Attempted import error: 'BaseContext' is not exported from '@gatsbyjs/reach-router' (imported as 'BaseContext')

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

[Runtime error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0enb.png)

[Warn when running "gatsby develop"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ1K6.png)

I am getting this warn and cannot run my gatsby site because of it. No idea what caused this warn but I've tried everything and cannot fix the issue. I ran "gatsby clean", recloned repo and still no luck. I was however able to run the code no problem from another computer. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Error in function RouteHandler in ./.cache/root.js:21
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Provider')

./.cache/root.js:21

Answer (score 0):

Turns out just needed to needed to hit it with a `npm install @gatsbyjs/reach-router` and fixed the problem